# Matlab code in latex

Tags: matlab

I want to put matlab code into my latex document and I saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78393).

However, I don't really see how this works. I entered the following code into my overleaf account :

```
\documentclass{article}
% http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function y = myfun(aa, sigma, options)

  sigma

  y = aa .* pdf('logn', aa, -0.5*sigma^2, sigma)

  %y = 1/(sigma.*sqrt(2.*pi)) .* exp((-((log(aa)+0.5*sigma.^2)).^2) ./ (2.*sigma.^2));
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But  I get the errror

```
LaTeX Error: File `mcode.sty' not found.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure whether `overleaf` supports that package. May be it is good to check with their CS, I think.

Comment: Just upload `mcode.sty` into your project and everything will work.